# Define a field in Filemaker by date

Tags: filemaker

In FileMaker 12 I'm trying to define a field based on a date, but it's not working. Here's what I'm using for the definition for fieldB: If (fieldA < 10/1/2014; "old"; "new"). Any suggestions?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Please provide some details about what result you expect and what result you're getting. What are some example values of Field A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without more information (see comment on original post), but I just noticed that you've written the comparison `fieldA < 10/1/2014`. To FileMaker's calculation engine, that means "10, divided by 1, divided by 2014".

UPDATE: As @michael.hor257k pointed out, just wrapping it in quotes (`"10/1/2014"`) is not enough. However, you can both wrap it in quotes and use `GetAsDate()` as follows:

```
 If ( fieldA < GetAsDate ( "10/1/2014" ) ; "old" ; "new" )
```

Comment: "*You may be able to fix it just by wrapping the comparison date in quotes*" No, you need to compare a date to a date, not to a string.

Answer (score 2):

> Here's what I'm using for the definition for fieldB: If (fieldA <
>   10/1/2014; "old"; "new").

`10/1/2014` is a mathematical operation that results in about `0.005`, and no date will ever be less than that.

Here's what you *should* be using:

```
If ( fieldA < Date ( 10 ; 1 ; 2014) ; "old"; "new" )
```

This assumes that:

1. `fieldA` is a Date field;
2. the cut-off date is October 1, 2014 (otherwise you need to use `Date ( 1 ; 10 ; 2014)`.